# ASP.net AJAX Call doesn't work on 2nd click

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have an ASP.net webforms application that has a client-side click event that makes an Ajax call (XMLHttpRequest) to a page that calls a long-running web service.

The flow goes like this:

> Page1.aspx clicks on link that calls Page2.aspx
>
> Page2.aspx uses a delegate and IAsyncResult to make a call to WebService.asmx
>
> WebService.asmx uses an extended BackgroundWorker to to do work on separate thread

The IAsyncResult calls BeginInvoke() and then EndInvoke()

**The problem:**  Clicking on the link on Page1.aspx works fine the first time - Page 1 calls Page 2, who calls the Webservice, and the work gets done.

If I click on the link again (after the WebService work is done), it doesn't fire off the work the Page2.aspx is supposed to call.

When I debug through, I have a Javascript alert from Page1.aspx that says the XMLHttpRequest.send() request was called; however, the debugger doesn't bring me to the Page2.aspx page...in fact, it doesn't bring me anywhere.

Below is the inside of my Ajax function:
    var xmlhttp = null;

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "Page2.aspx?SomeQueryString=" + someID, true);
xmlhttp.send();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {               
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        try {
            var responseText = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("_lblExportStatus").innerHTML = responseText;
        }
        catch (e) {
             alert("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
   }
}
return false;
```

**Edit**
I've found that passing a different querystring to the XMLHttpRequest object does result in work being done.  The problem is with passing the exact same string in the Open() method.  Sending different strings to the open() method works fine.

Comment: Where is the logic that wires up the link(s) to the AJAX function?

Comment: That logic is in-line Javascript code on Page1.aspx. The LinkButton control that calls the Javascript has a backend call:  _lnkExport.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return doBenefitExport(" + _parsedBenefit.Id + ");");

Comment: can you do alert before xmlhttp.open("Get"). in that alert check your url is building correctly and valid also check code is actually executing correctly up to this level..

Comment: I've put in debug Javascript alert() calls before the .open() and after the .send().  The alert I put before the open() showed the URL I passed to open(), and it showed appropriately.

Comment: I've also found that even after navigating away from this page and returning, I'm still unable to successfully make the call...

Comment: the reason second call is being failed due to GET method as the page result data get cached...use POST instead of GET    more information                 http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **POST** instead OF **GET** if its still not works then use

**jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX** page methods or simply call **web service** directly using

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "Page2.aspx?SomeQueryString=" + someID, true);
 data: "{}",
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(msg) {
  // Do something interesting here.
 }
 });
```

link: [more information]

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

hope this helps

regards

Shaz

Comment: This is the answer - using POST instead of GET. Problem solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To overcome caching issue, you can use timestamp as unique token - i.e.:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "Page2.aspx?SomeQueryString=" + someID + 
"&timestamp=" + (new Date()).toString(), true);
```

Comment: That's a great idea too.  I'd like to mark this as the answer, but the answer suggesting POST instead of GET is probably 1/10% better than this one, although this solution makes me feel like a dunce that I didn't think of it.  Thanks!